# sed replace only particular word that matches in a file not all

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file named abcd.txt that contains

```
abcd  apple1
xyz apple
hi applea
hello applez
very apple2
good apple11
pink apple
red applee
```

i want to replace only apple with orange using sed i.e,
my output should be like this

```
abcd  apple1
xyz orange
hi applea
hello applez
very apple2
good apple11
pink orange
red applee
```

i used a sed command like

```
sed -i 's/apple/orange/' abcd.txt
```

i did not get the required output
please some one suggest me the proper command for this..

Answer (score 1):

Just use word boundary,

```
sed -i 's/\bapple\b/orange/' abcd.txt
```